# http redirects to https unless one page

Tags: .htaccess, https

I have this in my .htaccess file, to redirect all HTTP to HTTPS:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.sientemarruecos.viajes/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But now, due to e-commerce notifications, one page: `http ://www.sientemarruecos.viajes/?wc-api=WC_redsys` (**NOT** the home page)

Must **NOT** be redirectered. Could anyone tell me how to do it? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
#skip all rewriteRules bellow if the request is for "/?wc-api=WC_redsys"
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /\?wc-api=WC_redsys\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.sientemarruecos.viajes/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Yes!!!!!!!!!!!! Thanks a lot. Really. I have tried lost of codes, but it didn't do anything, or redirected to the home page, an so.

Really, thanks a lot.